# How to add a dynamic textfield in a label?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I want to create an app which helps me to improve on my English. I have a couple of English sentences stored via Realm on the device which will be displayed in the app. I have to enter the correct verb form including the tense. I used Apples Natural Language Module to filter out the verb forms and replace it with underscores.
The sentences are displayed in a UILabel, but instead of underscores, I want to have a UITextfield where the underscores are (so inside the label), so that I can write directly in the sentence instead of having a UITextfield below the sentence. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Oh and I already thought about having the full sentence just in a UITextfield so that I can edit everything, but since I might wanna publish the app it would be a little messy to let users delete parts of the sentence.

Comment: You can do this by using one temporary UITextField. Add one temp text field and set zero height width and make it hidden so user can not see. Now when user click to label then call text field should become active method and add text, inside the change character method replace underscores with input character by ranges or using replace occurrence.

Comment: Okay thanks, but how can I get the coordinate in the string to place the UITextField?